# Creating a function from a member of an instance for another instance in python

Tags: python, class, function, copy, member

Imagine that i have `f` which is a function of a member of a class instance:

```
class A:
    def b(self):
        print 'hey'

a = A()
f = a.b
```

If I have another instance of the same class, let's say `c = A()` how can I reconstruct a new `ff` only using `f` and `c`, so calling `ff()` would result in `c.b()` instead of `a.b()`?

```
c = A()
ff = some_python_kungfu(f,c)
ff() #it is calling c.b()
```

Comment: Your example would be less confusing if you chose more descriptive variable names. F THE BE THE C THE FF THE A hurts my eyes. (I'm just sayin'!)

Comment: The folks that are supposed to maintain this will -- of course -- hate you for making `ff` so complex when `c.b()` would have been so much simpler and more clear.  What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: @S.Lott The reason of doing this is to duplicate a network of objects that have functions of each other stored in atributes. I realize that in the long run I'll have to find a less confusing approach, but for now this seems the more logical way.

Comment: @jathanism Sorry, next time I'll be using official placeholder names as eggs and spam at least.

Comment: @ChAoS: Rather than waste time on this, why not actually post your actual question: "How to store method names as an attribute" or "how to "duplicate" (clone, deep copy, shallow copy) a network of objects." or something that actually applies to your actual problem.  For example `a.the_method= a.b` might be a whole lot smarter than `f=a.b` when "duplicating" this structure.

Comment: @S.Lott I didn't realize at the time what my actual problem was. I'll go for the answer by Cixate which answer my actual problem instead of this particular question.

Comment: @ChAoS:   "I didn't realize at the time what my actual problem was".  How can that be true?  This sounded like a very nice definition of what your problem actually was.  "The reason of doing this is to duplicate a network of objects that have functions of each other stored in atributes".  Is this still not your actual problem?  Can you clarify what your problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to know how to rebind an already bound method to another instance, using only the bound method and the other instance. It can be done like this:

```
def some_python_kungfu(meth, obj):
    return type(meth)(meth.__func__, obj, obj.__class__)
```

The `__func__` attribute is really [the same](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) as Ned Batchelders `im_func`, but `__func__` is forward-compatible with python 3.

There is one case where this will not work: methods of built-in classes. The `__func__` and `im_func` attributes are only available on user-defined classes. Therefore, this will fail:

```
a = "that's no ordinary rabbit"
b = "consult the book of armaments"
b_split = some_python_kungfu(a.split, b)
```

A slight modification of Ned's solution *will* work on both built-in and user-defined classes:

```
def some_python_kungfu(meth, obj):
    return getattr(obj, meth.__name__)
```

So will this always work then? Well... no, but the stumbling block a rather obscure and (I guess) seldom occuring problem: if the name of the method (`meth.__name__`) is not the same as the name it has in the class dictionary (`'b'`), then `getattr` will either return the wrong attribute or raise an `AttributeError`. For example:

```
def external(self):
   pass
class A(object):
   b = external
```

Here `A.b.__name__ == 'external'` instead of `'b'`, so `getattr(obj, 'external')` will be called instead of `getattr(obj, 'b')`.

While both previous approaches have problems, one with **built-in classes** and one with **patched-together classes**, both problems do not occur simultaneously in any circumstance. Therefore, a *combination* will work in all cases:

```
def some_python_kungfu(meth, obj):
    try:
        return type(meth)(meth.__func__, obj, obj.__class__)
    except AttributeError:
        # meth is a built-in method, so meth.__name__ is always correct
        return getattr(obj, meth.__name__)
```

As explained elsewhere on this page, your best bet would probably be to ignore this whole mess and do it some cleaner way, like for instance using the *unbound* methods and passing in the first argument (`self`) manually, as in Cixates answer. But who knows, this may prove useful to some of you some day perhaps, in a somewhat bizarre set of circumstances. ;)

Comment: A very complete answer to the asked question!

Answer (score 4):

Can you use a method reference for the class instead of the instance reference?

```
class A:
    def whoami(self):
        print 'I am %s' % id(self)

a = A()
c = A()

func = A.whoami

func(a)
func(c)
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be the way to go in the long term!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this would work in all cases, but:

```
def some_python_kungfu(meth, obj):
    """Get a bound method on `obj` corresponding to the method `meth`."""
    return getattr(obj, meth.im_func.__name__)
```

Comment: I wish I could mark more than one answer as the selected one! +1 for answering quickly.